# DownloadString and web exception(The operation has timed out)

Tags: c#, html, web

I get page source with below code. after it takes second page's source code it gives  web exception which says "The operation has timed out" How can I solve this?

```
     Uri url = new Uri(urlAddress);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");                     
        string htlm = client.DownloadString(url);
        return htlm;
```

Comment: You need to extend the connection timeout of the client.This is done by inheriting the existing web client and increasing the timeout of the web request. There is a better explanation on how to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object

Comment: @nsgocev I tried but it doenst work I guess because the asker says the site too slow that causes the time out. The site I try to get source isn't slow

Comment: The site is quick in your browser but times out in your code? How long does it take to timeout?

Comment: do you mind giving the link?

Comment: e.g these 3 links http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/yazarlar/24420135.asp , http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/yazarlar/24412055.asp ,  http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/yazarlar/24408289.asp  @DavidG it takes first and second in like 2-3 seconds. but when it comes to third it stucks

Comment: I've tried all 3 addresses using the same code as you and it works fine. Do you have any proxy server or firewall in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this question [DownloadString timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814001/downloadstring-timed-out) . It is identical to your question.  But in this case you should use something like

```
    oClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0");
```

instead of

```
 oClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

Comment: If it's identical to another answer, make a comment, not an answer.